# how to make layer of paragraph over heading

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am making paragraph data to appear when we hover over heading which is over image, the paragraph will as gradient from right side. [Here the code](https://codepen.io/asfafasa/pen/eYmGxLe) help me please to write.
the data should be align to right side not covering the whole pagethis code

```
  .align-center{
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.image-cover-3{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;
    line-height: 250px;
    background-size: cover;
  text-align: center;
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7),rgba(100,167,87,.48)), url("https://i.ibb.co/HK8v8W3/buiding.jpg");
}

.head-size-2{
    font-size: 40px;
}

.rearrange-img{
    display: inline-flex;
    vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: normal;     
    position: relative;
    color: aliceblue;
}

.image-cover-3:hover .head-size-2{
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 300ms;
    -moz-transition: opacity 300ms;
    -o-transition: opacity 300ms;
    transition: opacity 300ms;
}

.image-cover-3 .head-size-3{
    opacity: 0;
    font-size: 20px;
    display: flex;
    vertical-align: middle;     
    color: aliceblue;
    top: -150px;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms;
    -moz-transition: opacity 500ms;
    -o-transition: opacity 500ms;
    transition: opacity 500ms;
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(1, 0, 0, 0.4),rgba(100,167,87,.48));
    height: 100%;
    width: 1200px;
}

.image-cover-3:hover .head-size-3{
    opacity: 0.8;
}
```

Comment: Do you want the paragraph over the full image right?

Answer (score 0):

> Welcome to SO! I think this is what you want

```css
.align-center{
 text-align: center;
 display: inline-block;
 margin:0 auto;
 margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.image-cover-3{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 250px;
 line-height: 250px;
 background-size: cover;
  text-align: center;
 background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7),rgba(100,167,87,.48)), url("https://i.ibb.co/HK8v8W3/buiding.jpg");
position: relative;
}

.head-size-2{
 font-size: 40px;
}

.rearrange-img{
 display: inline-flex;
 vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: normal;     
 position: relative;
 color: aliceblue;
}

.image-cover-3:hover .head-size-2{
 opacity: 0;
 -webkit-transition: opacity 300ms;
    -moz-transition: opacity 300ms;
    -o-transition: opacity 300ms;
    transition: opacity 300ms;
}

.image-cover-3 .head-size-3{
 opacity: 0;
 font-size: 20px;
 display: flex;
 vertical-align: middle;     
 color: aliceblue;
 top: 0px;
 -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms;
    -moz-transition: opacity 500ms;
    -o-transition: opacity 500ms;
    transition: opacity 500ms;
 background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(1, 0, 0, 0.4),rgba(100,167,87,.48));
 height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    POSITION: ABSOLUTE;
    LEFT: 0;
    RIGHT: 0;
    align-items: center;
}

.image-cover-3:hover .head-size-3{
 opacity: 0.8;
}
```

```html
<section><div class="image-cover-3">
<h2  class="rearrange-img head-size-2">About the International Confrence on Industry 4.0 & Circular Economy</h2>
 <div class="align-center rearrange-img head-size-3">
  The conference widens the scope of bringing together innovators, researchers and industries under common goal – creating, evaluating, implementing and benefiting from innovations. It will thus support innovative projects in Mechanical engineering and bring benefits to all involved participants
    </div>
 </div>
 </section>
```